# Add multiple fields to webform on ASP.Net with just one button click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a webform in ASP.Net (Visual Studio). I have two buttons on the form, one button (button 1) submits the form and another button (button 2) would be used to add additional fields to the forms. I want to be able to click Button 2 to add all of the fields that are currently on the form with just one click. The user should also be able to add up to 20 such sets of additional fields. Thanks!

Comment: A data-bound repeater would be much easier. Using dynamic controls in webforms is awkward.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code or example that can be used to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: [Check out some existing resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+repeater&oq=asp.net+repeater&aqs=chrome..69i57.2934j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Will it be possible to send the values of the added fields to a SQL table?

Comment: Yes.Any data-bound control will give you access to the data and some of them have built-in capability to wire up database operations. I suggest repeater because of the structure it appears you want to build, but you could also [compare the options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx)

Comment: Will it be possible for you at all to provide a sample code that I can use for my form? I am getting a bit confused at the moment after looking at the videos and several websites. Appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not do better than the examples and samples you can find online. I haven't done webforms for years so I would have to build something, but I would just end up googling it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with WebForms, but using VB.Net. I will try guide you through the steps, but you gotta use the syntax of c#.

Basically, all ASP:Buttons will submit the form. What you actually mean is, when you press button2, there should be a method handling button2. In that method, you can create dynamic controls. Example:

protected sub addFields() handles button2.click {

```
   Dim field1 as type;

   Dim field2 as type;

   set properties of the fields;


   //you need to place a placeholder on the aspx page

   id_of_placeholder.controls.add(field1); -> so on
```

}

Now all fields are added, using viewstate you can store and retrieve how many times button2 has been clicked.

When a postback is done, all dynamically added fields are lost, because ASP.Net tracks only controls on the aspx page. You need to rebuild them on the page_load method (by knowing how many times the user clicked on button2, you can create a loop and add the fields back). Because the dynamically added controls are lost, the data they hold are lost too!! Use an ASP:HiddenField on the aspx page, so that a javascript can put user selected data into it.

Pseudo code:
js:

```
for each field {
    //clientidmode = "static" can be used to make the id of hiddenfield predicatable
    getHiddenField.text = getHiddenField.text + field.text + ",";
}
```

c#:
page_load method {

```
get viewstate containing button2 clicks;
string userdata = hiddenfield.text

for i = 0 to clicks - 1 {
    add fields
    //comma used as data seperator
    for i = 0 to fieldscount {
        //field(i) standing for each field
        //substring, so we get the first data and assign it to field
        field(i).data = userdata.substring(0, userdata.firstIndexOf(","));
        //now delete the retrieved data, so we can loop
        userdata.removeTheDataBeforeFirstComma;
    }
}
```

}

After this, you should be able to dynamically add controls, display them and retrieve their data on postback.

When you reached this point, try to store the fields in Viewtate. This way, no need to use hiddenfields, just look if the field Viewtate exist, if so, add them.

Regards

Maheshvara